# Ubuntu 17.04 - USB backup

Tags: usb, backup, sync, automation

Is there a way to copy a folder to removable media, but only copying files and subfolders that are different to those on the removable media already?

Comment: Try [rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync) command.

Answer (score 4):

### You can use `rsync`

I often use the following command line to test what would happen, 'dry run',

```
sudo rsync -Havn source-dir/ target-dir
```

and the following command line to do the job,

```
sudo rsync -Hav source-dir/ target-dir
```

**Edit:**

I use `sudo`, when running locally in order to be able to preserve ownership and permissions, which is very important for system files and configuration files. If you want to do the same, please use a linux file system, for example `ext4` in the external drive.

If you 'only' copy data files (documents, pictures, multimedia files ...) you need not worry about permissions and can use a simpler `rsync` command line

**(End of edit)**

Notice the trailing slash. See

```
man rsync
```

for details about the trailing slash and the parameters (`-H,` `-a`, `-v`, `-n` and `-t`)

---

```
You use rsync in the same way you use rcp. You must specify a source and a des‐
tination, one of which may be remote.

Perhaps the best way to explain the syntax is with some examples:

    rsync -t *.c foo:src/

This  would  transfer all files matching the pattern *.c from the current direc‐
tory to the directory src on the machine foo. If any of the files already  exist
on the remote system then the rsync remote-update protocol is used to update the
file by sending only the differences in the data.  Note that  the  expansion  of
wildcards  on the commandline (*.c) into a list of files is handled by the shell
before it runs rsync and not by rsync itself (exactly  the  same  as  all  other
posix-style programs).

    rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp

This  would  recursively  transfer  all  files from the directory src/bar on the
machine foo into the /data/tmp/bar directory on the local machine. The files are
transferred  in  "archive"  mode,  which  ensures  that symbolic links, devices,
attributes, permissions, ownerships, etc. are preserved in the transfer.   Addi‐
tionally,  compression  will  be used to reduce the size of data portions of the
transfer.

    rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp

A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an  addi‐
tional  directory  level at the destination.  You can think of a trailing / on a
source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy  the
directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory
are transferred to the containing directory on the destination.  In other words,
each of the following commands copies the files in the same way, including their
setting of the attributes of /dest/foo:

    rsync -av /src/foo /dest
    rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo

Note also that host and module references don’t require a trailing slash to copy
the  contents  of  the  default  directory.  For example, both of these copy the
remote directory’s contents into "/dest":

    rsync -av host: /dest
    rsync -av host::module /dest

You can also use rsync in local-only mode, where both the source and destination
don’t have a ’:’ in the name. In this case it behaves like an improved copy com‐
mand.
```

Comment: For my local backups, I use   `sudo rsync --progress --delete --no-compress --exclude={.cache,.dbus} -avhH /home/chick/ /media/chick/Lbck/backup`